# Do i always need to create separate class for manytomany relation in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping

I was reading this article

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example/

But he created three classes

```
Stock
Category
stock_category
```

Do i always need separate table for relation or this can be done in 2 tables as well like only in Stock , Category

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Never.
This is common question that I have heard from many people. And the answer is that when you design entities :

**You MUST not think in terms of Relations (RDBMS) but you must think in terms of Objects (Java)**.

In more details. Hibernate attempts to achieve a quite difficult task : connect Object Oriented Universe of Java with Relational World. It achieves it in most of the cases on a price of confusion between two paradigms.

The best strategy (and less painful) is to design your entities and let Hibernate to create schema for you.
So assuming that

```
Stock entity refers to many categories (Set of Categories)
and
Category entity has a set of Stock ids
```

We have a many-to-many relationship navigable from both entities. *And you need only two classes here*.

Then you need to annotate (here I assume you are using annotations not .hbm.xml) these sets as many-to-many attributes (read the [Hibernate Annotation Manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/)).

Compile the code. Then [Configure Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#tutorial-firstapp-configuration) for automatic schema generation (hbm2ddl.auto is the property that enable schema generation). If everything is ok
you will see **3** tables in the database 2 tables for entities and 1 table for many-to-many association (this is the 3rd Normal Form of schema, eg the cleanest one).

Then persist some entities and enjoy. And never forget **Think in OO terms while using hibernate (there is no JOIN operation)**.

Comment: SO that  third table will be automatically generated or do i have create it. If hibernate create that , then what will be its name

Comment: Hibernate can create all needed tables *automatically*.

Answer (score 4):

You have many-to-many relationship, you will need a junction database table, in your case `Stock_Category` table. That said, that junction table may not need to show up in as a Hibernate entity, depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

If your junction table merely holds the primary keys from `Stock` table and `Category` table, then you can use `@ManyToMany`. In this case, the Stock entity will have `stock.getCategories()` that returns all categories, while Category entity will have `category.getStocks()` that returns all stocks. The junction table doesn't appear at all.

However, if you are going to have additional behavior(s) into `Stock_Category` table, for example, if you want to capture who assigns the stock to the category or when it is added, then you will need to use `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` instead of `@ManyToMany`. In this case, the junction table will appear as a Hibernate entity. So, the Stock entity will have `stock.getStockCategories()` that returns all the stock categories, while Category entity may also have `stock.getStockCategories()`  (if you configure bi-directional relationship) that returns the same thing. The `StockCategory` entity contains additional properties, such as `personWhoAddsTheStockIntoCategory` or `dateAdded`, etc...

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1: Keeping other info in the join table is a good reason for explicitly mapping it as an entity.

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate table for the join in a man-many relation.  You do not however need a separate Java class representing this join table.

In the cited article's code, `Stock` and `Category` both have `Set<StockCategory>` fields mapped with a `@OneToMany` annotation.  You could instead use `@ManyToMany` annotations and entirely avoid the `StackCategory` class.  The table would still have to exist and would be referenced in a `@JoinTable` annotation on one end of the relation.

See the [docs on mapping associations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-association) for more details on how to do this.

Answer (score -1):

You can't, in general, have two tables which have foreign key constraints on each other.  Moreover, you would end up with multiple almost-duplicate rows in each table, which would complicate using them in ways *not* involving the many-to-many relationship.

Comment: so u mean , for many to many, there has to have  relationship table , i mean three tables

Comment: Yes.  Even if you bypassed the foreign key constraints, you still would have a fairly unusable mess on your hands otherwise.