# What is correct way to use Hibernate, generate tables using entity or generate tables using db sql file

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am working on the application which have 10-15 tables and I will using Hibernate for database access.
Now the question I have is, how to create a database for such application?
Should I let hibernate crate database by defining the entities or keep control of database with me by using schema.sql and data.sql.

If I let hibernate create tables, it always causes issues in future if database design changes. That is why I am inclined to use schema.sql and data.sql.

I mean, is there any best practice?
How to approach the design of the application, from database view or Java object view?

I read lot of questions on stackoverflow but there is no clean answer for the question.
I am looking for any link or topic where it is discussed.

I know both the way will work fine. I have found some comments which says the relation is DB is not necessay if you are using hibernate like https://stackoverflow.com/a/37925244/20688290 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/5204600/20688290 which says there is no need to maintain any relation in DB if using Hibernate.

Comment: Usualy the DB is SSOT and SVOT. Have you concidered to use Liquibase?

Comment: varies for use-cases. I hope the discussion here will serve your quest - https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2436090

Answer (score 0):

It's up to your choice, if you have less requirements you can utilize Hibernate to automatically update database tables.

However if you want to try any other alternatives, I recommend you to use Liquibase.

Check out this link for your reference [Integrating liquibase with spring boot](https://medium.com/@vamsibvrit559/integrating-liquibase-with-spring-boot-8998905b3f06)